# two dimensional interval matrix

Tags: c++, data-structures

I have to implement a 2 dimensional interval matrix something like:

```
            Weight Range.
AgeRange.   7-10kg       11-17kg      18-30kg       31-60kg     61-80kg...
1  - 10       0             0           0              0           0
11 - 20       0             0           0              0           0
21 - 30       0             0           0              0           0
31 - 40       0             0           0              0           0
41 - 50       0             0           0              0           0
...
```

Let me call the above as AWMatrix.
My intervals are static, and will not be changed once built. initially all data is zero in the matrix

Operations to be supported:

```
AddData(Age, Weight): example AddDate(1, 9) will increment AWMatrix[0,0] by 1.
                      example AddDate(32, 74) will increment AWMatrix[3,4] by 1.
GetData(Age, Weight) : example GetData(32, 62) will return 1.
```

Both the age and weight intervals are NON-overlapping.

I have read about interval trees/segment trees. Are these the way to go, or do we have something more specialised that I can use here?? I am using C++.

Comment: For age Range, it seems that `(age - 1) / 10` does the conversion as wanted.

Comment: wow, what's the matter with those funky gray squares?!

Answer (score 1):

Following may help:

```
std::pair<std::size_t, std::size_t>
GetIndexes(std::size_t age, std::size_t weight)
{
    if (age == 0) { // Maybe high limit
        throw std::out_of_range("Bad age value");
    }
    if (weight < 7 ) { // Maybe high limit
        throw std::out_of_range("Bad weight value");
    }
    // age_index can be computed simply
    // but age_index can be found in a similar way that weight_index
    const std::size_t age_index = (age - 1) / 10; 

    const std::vector<int> v = { 6, 10, 17, 30, 60, 80 };
    const std::size_t weight_index = std::lower_bound(v.begin(), v.end(), weight) - v.begin();

    return std::make_pair(age_index, weight_index - 1);
}
```

So `GetIndexes(32, 74) == GetIndexes(32, 62) == std::make_pair(3u, 4u)`

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple approach to solve this problem. To perform operation `AddData(age, weight)` , find the `age-interval(or row)` which contains `age`, find the `weight-interval (or column)` which contains the `weight` and then perform operation `AWMatrix[row][column]++`.The result of the operation `GetData(age,weight)` is given by `AWMatrix[row][column]`.
Hence the problem reduces to point(or element) updation and point(or element) query in a matrix. Since segment trees are used to solve problems involving `point updation-range query` or `range updation-point query`, there is no need to use segment tree here.
Let us assume there are `n` age intervals and `m` weight intervals. If we store both these `age-intervals` and `weight-intervals` in a `sorted vector` or a `map`, then `age-interval` or `row` computation will be `O(log(n))`, `weight-interval` or `column` computation will be `O(log(m))`, rest of the operations will be `O(1)`.
Hence `Time Complexity = O(log(m) + log(n))`, `Space Complexity =O(n*m)`.

If number of `(row,col) pairs` is much less than `O(n*m)` and we want to reduce the space complexity, then we can use the following approach. 
Make a map : `map< pair<row,col> , val>`. 
Operation `AddData(age, weight)` is as follows : 
 
`if(map.find(make_pair(row,col))!=map.end())` 
`map[make_pair(row,col)]++;` 
`else` 
`map[make_pair(row,col)]=1;`

Operation `GetData(age, weight)` is as follows : 
`if(map.find(make_pair(row,col))!=map.end())` 
`return(map[make_pair(row,col)]);` 
`else` 
`return(0);`

Time Complexity = `O(log(m)+log(n)+log(number of (row,column) pairs))` 
Space Complexity = `O(number of (row,col) pairs)`.